# complex content references: which solution? views (big query) OR non-views db_select() OR many node_loads OR

Tags: views, database

I have content type that links to several other content types

Report -> Plot -> Dataset -> Citation (biblio).

This type has a conditional field which selectively links to to possibilities each with field collections and entity references.

I want to show information from each of these together.  These are the options I'm considering:

1) I can do this with views.  It turns out that the 'table' type (a $rows array makes it easy than inspecting the $views object) and several relations can put something that works together.  The query is quite big with at least 10 LEFT JOINs, and it does seem a bit kludgy (I have to modify the 'tables' template and strip out the  html and a lot of the class info.  The solution I want isn't a table, and I'm not sure this is the best way.)

2) I could skip views and develop my own module/block use db_select(). This would allow me to simplify the query with a UNION.  But I have to so a lot more work on my own when views does a lot of the work for me.

3) I could skip views, develop my own module/block use a smaller query and with enough entity_loads and node_loads I can get all the info I need.  The problem having so many 'mini-queries' with all the node-loads seems like an inefficient way of doing things..

What is the recommended solution for something like this?

thanks!

Comment: I should note that I don't think these relations can be simplified any further because each is in a many-to-many relation (or at least 1-to-many).